# When creating a stored procedure in oracle, it appears to execute, but it does nothing. The stored procedure never gets saved. Why?

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle SQL using `TOAD`, but it's not doing anything. There's no error, no message, no nothing, when attempting to create it. It just seems to have gone through, but it doesn't.

The query looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PottyUseRange (formatty varchar2, start varchar2, end varchar2)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT TO_CHAR(TIME_RANGE, formatty) as CURRENT_DATE,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'LM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LM_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'AO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AO_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'RO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RO_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'FL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FL_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY IN ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL           
        FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE to_char(TIME_RANGE, formatty) >= to_char(start, formatty)
            AND to_char(TIME_RANGE, formatty) <= to_char(end, formatty)
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(TIME_RANGE, formatty)
        ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TIME_RANGE, formatty)  ASC;

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            raise_application_error(-20001,'Proc failed - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    END;
```

And when I attempt to call it (I'm aware it's an empty query, but it will let me know if it exists or not):

```
BEGIN
    POTTYUSERANGE();
END;
```

I get this error: `PLS-00201: identifier 'POTTYUSERANGE' must be declared`

When I call it using `CALL POTTYUSERANGE();`, I get this error: `ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name`

How do I properly create a stored procedure for this query?

**UPDATE**

I need to insert this into a `BULK COLLECTION` and return it to the user. It has to be limited so it doesn't cause excessive memory consumption. These are rather large result sets, and they look like this:

```
+--------------+----+----+----+----+-------+
| CURRENT_DATE | LM | AO | RO | FL | TOTAL |
+--------------+----+----+----+----+-------+
|  1/2/2012    | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 |  10   |
+--------------+----+----+----+----+-------+
|  1/4/2013    | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |  14   |
+--------------+----+----+----+----+-------+
```

Do I need a view? Stored proc? What do I need?

Comment: Oracle stored procedures don't just run SQL.  What do you want to do with the results?  Do you really want a view or user-defined function?

Comment: Possibly. I want to take these results and return them to the user. There's a date format (`formatty`), and then a start date (`start`), and end date (`end`). I want the user to be able to send a query with those parameters, and return the results to them. What would be the correct option for that?

Comment: Your procedure has **compilation errors**. So, you can't execute it unless you solve the compilation errors. Also, you cannot use a `SELECT` statement in `PL/SQL` without an **INTO clause**`.

Comment: Yes, but the compilation errors aren't showing to me, so I have no idea where I'm going wrong. There are no errors, no warnings, no messages, nothing. I've always gotten errors before when I ended up writing invalid SQL, so I knew where to look. How would I go about doing this correctly? Thank you.

Comment: In `SQL*Plus`, after compiling the procedure, do this `SHOW ERRORS`

Comment: Also see, [WHEN OTHERS](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, what is the purpose of this procedure? What are you wanting to do with the results of the query?

Comment: I'd like to return the data to the user that calls the stored procedure. Right now I'm trying to learn stored procedures, so I'm trying to figure out how to create one successfully using some my previous select statements.

Comment: and by "user" do you mean someone running the procedure in Toad, or do you mean a calling program (eg. a webservice etc)? Because if the latter, then I would recommend returning a ref cursor and having the calling program handle that. If it's the former, then I'd suggest a view instead.

Comment: Also, in Toad, how are you attempting to compile the code? I've had problems in some versions of Toad where using F9 / Execute Statement fails to run the `create or replace ...` code, but F5 / Execute as script works just fine. If in doubt, highlight the procedure and run it as a script.

Comment: By user, I mean the program that will eventually call the stored procedure. Right now I'm testing it out. Oh, here we go... compiled, but with compilation errors. I've been using `F9 / Execute Statement` instead of `F5 / Execute as Script`.

Comment: `I need to insert this into a BULK COLLECTION` .... I would highly recommend returning a ref cursor instead. This returns a pointer to the cursor, and allows the calling code to pull the data across as and when it needs it, almost as if the calling code had run the SQL directly. Much better, IMO, than collecting everything into a collection and then passing it across in one big lump!

Comment: `SQL*Plus` is free, why not use it at times like this? I know at times GUI based client tools are handy, but, I always found SQL*Plus the best at such issues.

Comment: A very basic question, do you really need `PL/SQL` to achieve your task? Can't you use plain `SQL`?

Comment: `PL/SQL` was specifically requested, and this is an Oracle database. However, if plain SQL can do this, I'm interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, this is how I'd code the above procedure:

```
create or replace procedure pottyuserange (p_date_format in varchar2,
                                           p_start_date in varchar2,
                                           p_end_date in varchar2,
                                           p_ref_cursor out sys_refcursor)
as
begin
  open p_ref_cursor for 
    select   to_char(time_range, p_date_format) as current_date,
             lm_search,
             ao_search,
             ro_search,
             fl_search,
             total
    from     (select   trunc(time_range) time_range,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'LM' then 1 else 0 end) as lm_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'AO' then 1 else 0 end) as ao_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'RO' then 1 else 0 end) as ro_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'FL' then 1 else 0 end) as fl_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty in ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') then 1 else 0 end) as total           
              from     core.date_test
              where    trunc(time_range) >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
              and      trunc(time_range) <= to_date(p_end_date, p_date_format)
              group by trunc(time_range))
    order by time_range asc;
end pottyuserange;
/
```

Note:

1. the addition of the out parameter to return the cursor
2. the additon of the `open p_ref_cursor for` line, which is what creates the pointer to the cursor
3. the changing of the predicates to do the date comparison as DATEs rather than strings
4. the addition of the procedure name after the closing `END` line
5. much clearer names for the parameter names. I would recommend changing the name of the procedure to something clearer too - that way, your code becomes much more self-documenting and easier to maintain in the future.
6. the way I've moved the base of the query into a subquery and changed the outer query to order by the time_range field directly - since this is still in DATE format, it will order the results as expected. Thanks to Alex Poole for pointing out the issue with the ordering.

As for your issues running this in Toad, some versions of Toad have a bug (in my experience) where running the code via the Execute as statement / F9 button fails to do anything. If this is the case, try running it as a script (F5).

---

To test the above procedure in Toad (as a script) or in SQL*Plus, run the following:

```
variable rc refcursor;

begin
  PottyUseRange('YYYY-MM-DD', '1/1/2008', '10/12/2015', :rc);
end;
/

print rc;
```

(This creates a SQLPlus variable "rc", which you pass into the procedure as a bind variable. You can then use the SQLPlus print function to loop through and display the results.)

---

FWIW, here's what I see when I run show errors in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Oct 12 17:34:32 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create or replace procedure test
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end test;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors;
No errors.
SQL>
```

Comment: Add the differences between `F9 - Execute as Statement` and `F5 - Execute as Script`, as you mentioned earlier, and this will be the accepted answer. That, combined with `SHOW ERRORS`, and `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS` solved this problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that `SHOW ERRORS` is a SQL*Plus command, so only works if you run the whole thing as a script. However, I've found that `SHOW ERRORS` doesn't always show the errors, so `select * from user_errors;` is what I tend to use, as that always shows the errors (at least, in my experience!)

Comment: I wasn't able to execute `SHOW ERRORS` in SQL*Plus. It just sat there doing nothing. I'm using a grossly-outdated version of `TOAD`, though. It's probably outdated by a few years. As for the variable names, I'm aware, and I change them before posting them. All of them are random/fake, but it's good you pointed these out, so it'll help others.

Comment: You've left a couple of references to `formatty`, but I think the OP got the gist *8-) But might be worth mentioning that the ordering might not be as expected if the format isn't something that sorts helpfully (e.g. DD/MM/YYYY)? And if you're changing names, not too keen on the `current_date` alias - it works but could be a bit confusing.

Comment: Dates vary between `YYYY-MM-DD`, `YYYY/MM/DD`, `MM/DD/YYYY`, etc. so I wanted the user to be able to chose their own format. If I choose the date type, it complains about a literal match.

Comment: dumb question, but did you hit enter? The command itself works fine for me when I run it in sqlplus; I'll edit the output I get in my answer.

Comment: Yup, of course I hit enter! :p But the SQL*Plus window was empty. It has lines like: 60... and if I type `SHOW ERRORS`, it said nothing at all. That was before I tried your code, and now it's working.

Comment: Good point, Alex! Also I fixed the stray formatty references that I meant to update, honest! *{;-)

Comment: Quick question: when trying to call it with these parameters, it shows up as: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to `. What gives? I'm using `PottyUseRange('YYYY-MM-DD', '1/1/2008', '10/12/2015');`

Comment: @SecuriTree - in SQL\*Plus you'd need [a slash on a line on its own](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663) to execute the buffer. IDEs may or may not expect it but it's usually safer to include it. And your call has to include the fourth argument that Boneist added, which has to be declared by the caller (as it's an OUT parameter). (You could also make it a function that returns a ref cursor instead)

Comment: @Boneist Are you sure about this `where    trunc(time_range) >= to_char(p_start_date, p_date_format)` It is comparing date on L.H.S. to a string on R.H.S. I think you missed it, else, it should have been `TO_DATE`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB dammit! Good spot *{;-) Fixed now; thanks!

Comment: @Boneist, You forgot another formatty. :P Also, `PottyUseRange('YYYY-MM-DD', '1/1/2008', '10/12/2015'); is giving me an error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to`

Comment: @AlexPoole I request you to please undelete your answer, as it has several important points.

Comment: I agree. Alex, please undelete your answer. I was just about to ask myself. You had a lot of really good advice in the post, and it will help others.

Comment: @SecuriTree hopefully, thanks to the help of Lalit and Alex, I've managed to knock the bugs out of the procedure in my answer. Hopefully you've followed and understood the changes I've made to your original procedure?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thirded on the undelete!

Comment: @LalitKumarB - well I'm nothing if not susceptible to peer pressure... I thought it was more noisy than helpful now this answer covers the major points more succinctly, but OK *8-)

Comment: @Boneist, I'm still stuck on the output variable. `wrong number or types of arguments in call to PottyUseRange` when using `CALL PottyUseRange('yyyy-mm-dd', '1/2/2010', '10/12/2015');` I'm not quite sure how to call the output variable and display results.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a way for you to call the procedure in Toad / SQL*Plus. How your calling procedure would handle the call, you'd have to google yourself. Basically, as there are four parameters (3 in and 1 out) to the procedure, you need to call the procedure with four parameters - 3 that you use to pass data in and 1 that you use to hold the data returned by the out parameter. Obviously, they'd need to be of the relevant datatype...

Answer (score 4):

You've declare the procedure as:

```
PottyUseRange (formatty varchar2, start varchar2, end varchar2)
```

But you're calling it with no arguments:

```
BEGIN
    POTTYUSERANGE();
END;
```

There is no procedure matching the call you made. You need to pass the appropriate number of parameters, which can be literal values here as they are all IN parameters, e.g.:

```
BEGIN
    POTTYUSERANGE('X', 'Y', 'Z');
END;
```

Though with more meaningful values, of course. You can also pass local variables instead of constant literals.

But you say you're getting `PLS-00201: identifier 'POTTYUSERANGE' must be declared` with one call, and `ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name` with another, which means you either aren't actually creating it at all (you're types the code i but not executed it), or you're working in two separate schemas. You haven't shown a schema prefix in the `create` call, so you may be removed that for privacy reasons, or you're creating and calling separate sessions. If your current user doesn't own the procedure and there isn't a synonym, you need to prefix it with the owner - guessing from the table owner:

```
BEGIN
    CORE.POTTYUSERANGE('X', 'Y', 'Z');
END;
```

---

As Lalit noted, you have compilation errors anyway, so calling would give `PLS-00905: object SCHEMA.POTTYUSERANGE is invalid`. You can see the errors with `show errors` or by querying the `user_errors` view (or `all_errors` if you're creating objects in another schema, which seems to be the case here), which would tell you:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "START" when expecting one of the following:

         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior
```

Start and end are reserved words. You can use more appropriate names (what is starting?) or a generic prefix like `p_`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PottyUseRange (p_formatty varchar2, p_start varchar2, p_end varchar2)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT TO_CHAR(TIME_RANGE, formatty) as CURRENT_DATE,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'LM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LM_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'AO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AO_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'RO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RO_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY = 'FL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FL_SEARCH,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PORTA_POTTY IN ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL           
        FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
            WHERE to_char(TIME_RANGE, p_formatty) >= to_char(p_start, formatty)
            AND to_char(TIME_RANGE, p_formatty) <= to_char(p_end, formatty)
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(TIME_RANGE, p_formatty)
        ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TIME_RANGE, p_formatty)  ASC;

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            raise_application_error(-20001,'Proc failed - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    END;
/
```

But you also need to [select into](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm) something when you're working in PL/SQL, e.g. declare local variables like `l_timerange` etc. if you're going to be doing something with them locally. But you seem to be expecting multiple values, so you'd need to [bulk select into a collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm#CJAIAGHJ). It isn't clear what this is supposed to achieve though. If you want to pass those values back to the caller it might be simpler to use a ref cursor to return the result set; but then it isn't really clear if you actually need a procedure/function at all, or just a plain SQL query, or perhaps a view...

As a further issue, you're comparing dates as strings, and grouping/ordering by those too:

```
to_char(TIME_RANGE, formatty) >= to_char(start, formatty)
```

Comparing will only work at all for certain formats, and as you're passing a variable format in that's asking for problems; and even when it works may not be efficient. Ordering will also only work for some formats - if it makes sense to order at all (again, depends what you're doing with the results!). Convert your passed start/end strings to dates using the format that's passed in, and compare those:

```
TIME_RANGE >= to_date(p_start, formatty)
```

... or if possible pass a date into the procedure instead of a string.

Catching exceptions like this is also dangerous. You're assuming that whoever calls the procedure will have server output enabled and will do something with the error. Unless you can sensibly handle an exception you shouldn't catch it, and certainly shouldn't squash it like this.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it with no arguments to make sure it exists. It doesn't. The query never gets created. I get the same error with X, Y, and Z. I should update the question to show I've tried that.

Comment: You can't call it with no arguments because you're trying to call a *different* procedure (because the specification is different).

Comment: I find two other serious issues. 1. `SELECT INTO` 2. `WHEN OTHERS` without `RAISE`. The exception block is itself a bug.

Comment: If it's called with no arguments, it will complain about a lack of arguments, meaning the stored procedure exists. Here, even with your method, I'm getting the same error: `PLS-00201: identifier 'POTTYUSERANGE' must be declared`

Comment: How do you confirm that your procedure has successfully compiled?

Comment: Okay, so *what* would I select the results into? It's a collection of data that appears like this: `CURRENT_DATE | LM | AO | RO | FL | TOTAL`

Comment: Exactly, how do I confirm that? It's not giving me any errors or anything. It's not showing anything, complaining at all, or doing anything. It's just sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: Now a days, GUI based client tools do have a SQL*Plus kind of window. So, could you compile the code, and do `SHOW ERRORS` to get the error stack. This is all about compile time errors. You need to take care of your exception block to make sure the run time errors are also meaningful.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user_errors`. Nothing shows up at all. `SHOW ERRORS` also does not work.

Comment: See the documentation on [SELECT INTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345)

Comment: @SecuriTree - are you creating it in your own schema? It looks like it from the create command but perhaps not. You may need to look in `all_errors` to find it. And what you select into depends on what you want to do with the results; if the caller needs the data back then what it's expecting or can handle will also matter. At the moment it isn't clear why you're using a stored procedure.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried your code, and have thrown out the exception block as well. With or without the exception block, it's not compiling, but it isn't telling me that it's not. I'm trying to query this within `TOAD` from the SQL script bench. I have tried selecting `SQL`, and `PLSQL`, and both have the same results: absolutely nothing. With `SHOW ERRORS`, I'm also getting nothing. When selecting `all_errors`, it returns empty results. There's no warning telling me that I'm doing something wrong. I've even tried running it in `Eclipse` and `NetBeans`. Same issue.

Comment: @SecuriTree I think that you come from a non-database background, most probably a front-end developer. All the suggestions here by me and others are to help you :-). Could you try the following steps: 1. `SQL*Plus` should be available with your database installation, so please open `SQL*Plus`, and compile your procedure and after that, do `SHO ERR`. 2. If you still fail to open `SQL*Plus`, then please google how to use show errors/`SQL*Plus` window in TOAD for Oracle. And repeat the steps. All the best!

Comment: Yep, front and back-end developer here. I am relatively new to databases, and appreciate the help. I tried that, and it came back with nothing at all. `SHOW ERRORS`, `SHOW ERROR`, `SHO ERR`, returns nothing. Apparently I needed to execute it as a script.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. I had to execute this as a script (`F5 - Execute as Script`, NOT `'F9 - Execute as Statement`) before the errors showed up in `USER_ERRORS`. Once I got there, I was able to fix all the problems in my code. At that point, I attempted to compile again, and it gave me this error: `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement` This means I need some kind of into/ref cursor, and I guess that's an entirely different question.

Comment: The INTO clause error is nothing but as I already said to look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345 Basically, `SQL` and `PL/SQL` engines are different, so you cannot directly execute a SQL statement in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should successfully compile the procedure before execute it.
To see compilation errors you can use `SHOW ERRORS`. From there you can get the errors in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

execute below query to know for errors while compilation

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS where lower(NAME) = 'pottyuserange ' and type = 'PROCEDURE'
```